# Как правильно, вызвать callback-метод активности через getActivity().onRequestPermissionsResult?

Tags: android

Как правильно, вызвать callback-метод активности через getActivity().onRequestPermissionsResult попутно переопределив его? Просто я не хочу захламлять активность вот этим кодом:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String 
permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения получены", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения не получены", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this);
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
grantResults);
    }
}
```

, а вызвать его при необходимость путем использования статического метода из  произвольного класса?

Comment: колбэки вызваются по событию, а не вашему желанию.

Comment: В принципе так и предполагал..., просто хотел убедиться что нет каких-либо способов перенести код связанный c Runtime Permissions в отдельный класс... Придется реализовать весь код в Активити...

Comment: Заведите себе BaseActivity и там добавьте эти методы.